# Is there a way to apply a CSS style to all the comments on the same level?

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a hierarchical comments structure, meaning there are multiple levels (parent, child, child's child etc.), and one each level there are multiple comments.

I would like to set the background of every second level (not comment) to some color. 
This means: all the comments on the same level have the same color, but the comments on the levels above and below both have a second, different color.

I played around a bit with li:nth-child, but I only managed to apply this to the comments themselves, not to the levels.

My comments structure looks liks this:

```
<ul class="tree-block">
  <li>
  <li>
   <div class="comment">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <div class="comment">
     <ul>
      <li>
       <div class="comment">
       <ul>
        <li>
```

Comment: How is the HTML code generated?

Comment: What @ŠimeVidas wants to tell you is to generate code with more comment classes, e.g. `comment odd` for odd-level comments and `comment even` for even-level. If you generate this in PHP (WordPress themes, for example), this is the most compatible and the easiest approach. Just toggle a boolean flag (`$is_odd_level`) every time you enter or leave a child loop for generating the markup and print the class name accordingly.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Changing the list itself is doable, although time-consuming. I would prefer a CSS-only approach, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
div.tree-block .comment { /* first level */ }
div.tree-block .comment .comment { /* second level */ }
div.tree-block .comment .comment .comment { /* third level */ }
```

Like this, the second and third level comments will inherit the first level comment style. You would need to overwrite the unwanted properties with other values. If you don't want that, use the '>' selector syntax (direct child of):

```
div.tree-block > ul > li > .comment { /* first level */ }
div.tree-block > ul > li > .comment > ul > li > .comment { /* second level */ }
div.tree-block > ul > li > .comment > ul > li > .comment > ul > li > .comment { /* third level */ }
```

I don't know a way to generally create a rule for every odd/even level, but you could hardcode these until you reach a reasonable depth, which will probably never occur (not many threads I have seen go deeper than 10 comments, probably only on reddit :D).

Comment: Hmm, probably not the best solution, but until someone posts something better I'm going to do it this way, it's certainly the easiest way. I hope you're right about the depth of the threads :P

Answer (score 0):

apply the css as its own coding with #comment{value1, value2, value3,...} and you can also place the css to the div container for all the items as well using #treeblock{value1, value2, value3} so on so forth.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Could you please be a bit more specific? Perhaps with an example?

Comment: on your css page you list the div id's that are unique as like this "#comment{ color: red; background-color: black; margin-left: 20%; ...} all your style tags can go per level.  You can even edit the name id for each comment container as comment1, comment2, comment3.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are explaining to me how basic CSS works. I already know that, that isn't the problem. The problem is the comment tree can have an infinite number of levels (not just the 3 levels I posted as an example), so the challenge is to somehow catch every second level and apply a different style to it. 

Also, I would rather not edit the IDs in the html itself. A pure CSS solution is preferable.

Comment: Then you can use the odd level and even level numbers as posted above my comment so it works to an infinite stage.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is very doable with nth-child. Here's a great tool I use that helps since it can get confusing:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Comment: Nope. The `:nth-child` does not care about levels. Read the OP.